# How to check the cache mode of a qcow2 image?

Tags: cache, qemu, qcow2

Say I converted an image to writethrough cache mode with this command:

```
qemu-img convert -t writethrough -O qcow2 in-image.qcow2 out-image.qcow2
```

How can I check/verify the cache mode of the image?